# unQL and Django?

Tags: django, nosql, couchdb, unql

sorry if this is too earlier to speak about that, but it seems that NoSQL and SQL has made something between them called UnQL (Sqlite and CouchDB), maybe i dident understand the concept, but if that UnQL will be aviable, so Django will behave with him as what? as an SQL or as a NoSql? since they said that the future release of Sqlite will have the UnQL support? and that concept is only restricted to CouchDB and not MongoDB? am really lost! will they add CouchDB options to Sqlite to call it UnQL since they say that Sqlite will have UnQL in the future?! what is that?

Answer (score 2):

> it seems that NoSQL and SQL has made something between them called
>   UnQL (Sqlite and CouchDB), maybe i dident understand the concept, but
>   if that UnQL will be aviable, so Django will behave with him as what?
>   as an SQL or as a NoSql?

Target of the [UnQL specification](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Home) is to offer the option/opportunity to implement open and unified querying language functionality among various NoSQL databases and their vendors. Queries in UnQL should be parsable to SQL in order to maintain some level of compatibility with RDBMS world.

> since they said that the future release of Sqlite will have the UnQL
>   support? and that concept is only restricted to CouchDB and not
>   MongoDB?

The UnQL specification is in it's early stages and although there are already some [prototype codes](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Prototype+Code+Repository), it's probably 6-8 months away from some major implementation from the side of database vendors. So far the UnQL participants include SQLite, CouchDB (and probably also Couchbase), but I think as time will go on and the specification will take it's form, more vendors would join the effort to participate and support this unified querying language. Concept is not restricted since the specification is open, so it's up to the database vendors if they will support the UnQL.

> will they add CouchDB options to Sqlite to call it UnQL since they say
>   that Sqlite will have UnQL in the future?! what is that?

CouchDB has nothing to do with SQLite and vice versa. Whether CouchDB, SQLite, MongoDB or whatever database will implement UnQL in the future is entirely up to it's vendors/developers.

Comment: thank you :)
so the UnQl is "a bridge" between NoSql and SQL?

Comment: @abdel: Main purpose is to have open and unified querying language with a hope that NoSQL database vendors would implement it, so that you don't have to learn proprietary languages when you are using multiple different database systems at the same time. Other purpose is the ability to parse UnQL queries into SQL ones in order to maintain compatibility with RDBMS world.

Comment: so it will be the best thing ever made! but, why i dont see big companies like Google vs Oracle ?

Comment: @abdel: Well, it's certainly a great stuff for NoSQL world and only time will tell if other big companies join the effort and adopt this specification.

Comment: hope so, and especially if they make another new UML for that!
[my question about uml and nosql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542140/which-diagram-to-use-in-nosql-mcd-merise-uml)