# which diagram to use in NoSql (Mcd, Merise, UML)

Tags: django, nosql, rdbms

again, sorry for my silly question, but it seems that what i've learned from Relation Database should be "erased", there is no joins, so how the hell will i draw use Merise and UML in NoSql?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

this one will not work for NoSql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How you organize your project is an independent notion of the technology used for persistence;  In particular; UML or ERD or any such tool doesn't particularly apply to relational databases any more than it does to document databases.

The idea that NoSQL has "No Joins" is both silly and unhelpful.  It's totally correct that (most) document databases do not provide a join operator; but that just means that when you do need a join, you do it in the application code instead of the query language;  The basic facts of organizing your project stay the same.

Another difference is that document databases make expressing some things easier, and other things harder.  For example, it's often easier to an entity relationship constraint in a relational database, but it's easier to express an inheritance heirarchy in a document database.  Both notions *can* be supported by both technologies, and you will certainly use them when your application needs them; regardless of the technology you end up using.

In short, you should design your application without first choosing a persistence technology.  Once you've got a good idea what you want to persist, You may have a better idea of which technology is a better fit.  It may be the case that what you really need is both, or you might need something totally different from either.

**EDIT**: The idea of a foreign key is no more magical than simply saying "This is a name of that kind of thing".  It happens that many SQL databases provide some very terse and useful features for dealing with this sort of thing; specifically, constraints (This column references this other relation; so it cannot take a value unless there is a corresponding row in the referant), and cascades, (If the status of the referent changes, make the corresponding change to the reference).  This does make it easy to keep data consistent even at the lowest level, since there's no way to tell the database to enter a state where the referent is missing.

The important thing to distinguish though, is that the idea of giving a database entity (A row in a relational database, document in document databases) is distinct from the notion of schema constraints.  One of the nice things about document databases is that they can easily combine or reorient where data lives so that you don't always have to have a referant that actually exists;  Most document databases use the document class as part of the key, and so you can still be sure that the key is meaningful, even if when the referent doesn't actually exist.

But most of the time, you actually *do* want the referent to exist; you don't want a blog post to have an author unless that author actually exists in your system.  Just how well this is supported depends a lot on the particular document database;  Some databases *do* provide triggers, or other tools, to enforce the integrity of the reference, but many others only provide some kind of transactional capability, which requires that the integrity be enforced in the application.

The point is; for most kinds of database, every value in the database has *some* kind of identifier;  in a relational database, that's a triple of relation:column:key; and in a document database it's usually something like the pair document_class:path.  When you need one entity to refer to another, you use whatever sort of key you need to identify that datum for that kind of database.  Foreign Key constraints found in RDBMses are just (really useful) syntactic sugar for "if not referant exists then raise ForeignKeyError", which could be implemented with equal power in other ways, if that's helpful for your particular use.

Comment: thank you,

the problem is that i want to make a thesis about a project that will need to write something in the thesis, and i'm sure that they'll correct the diagrams, 60% (or more) of the final project of an engineer here is based on the thesis, so i should find something to "draw", and because i've said: "okey, let's do something new" when i've tried to make a "conventional" Class Diagram, i've found that there is the problem of how do i connect keys...so do i re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Different Document databases express keys in different ways.  Some actually provide a serializable key that can be used for referencing other documents, while others simply index whatever, and leave you to define what a "key" must be.  This is equally true of RDBMses; Sqlite3 has `rowid`, a unique ID for every row in a table; many others have an optional autoincrement feature, and some require you to invent a key structure, with GUID's being a reccomended solution.

Comment: but in Sqlite, since it's a RDBMS, there are foreign keys, so you can represent the system as it was made with MySql, but how is this done when using MongoDB, it's documents? am new on it, and it seems it will use Pointers?